# Mongoose schema update is not pick it up by Mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I've my db already created where I have the following schema:

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    client: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'client'
    },
    group: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'project_group'
    }
});
```

I need to change the schema to

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    client: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'client'
    },
    group: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'project_group'
    }
});
```

because we need to force name to be unique and not null. After change this definition, I see that the db still saving documents with the same name value. My question is, how can I apply any change I've done in my schema? and, how can I do that automatically without doing this manually?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to index that field so it can be quickly searched. Then also restart your server, if you haven't already. It's easy to do if you have MongoDB Compass (the official MongoDB GUI), or you can read this doc.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-an-embedded-field